# Why does this criterion imply that $A$ is a subfield of $E$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

$E$ is an extension field of a field $F$ and $A$ is the subset of $E$ containing all the members algebraic over $F$. 
"To prove that $A$ is a subfield of $E$ it is enough to show that any two elements $u,v$ of $A$ lies in some finite extension $L$ of $F$."
I'm missing something simple, I know, but why is the quoted sentence correct?

Comment: I think I got it now, it's because then u+v and uv are algebraic, being in the finite extension, too, and any inverses would also be in those extensions.

Comment: Just stumped me for a bit for some reason